Finding number of differences between strings in Polars
I have a Polars dataframe in which the cells contain a sequence of single digits as a string of characters, and I want to find the number of differences between the elements of the string. For example:
df = pl.DataFrame({"pop_1": ["100","0021"],"pop_2":["11002","0000",]})

| pop_1 | pop_2   |
|_______|_________|
| "100" | "11002" |
| "0021"| "0000"  |

col_1 row1 has 2 differences with itself (1 different than 0 two times);
col_2 row1 has 8 differences with itself;
col_1 and col_2 have 9 differences between them at row1.
The naive implementation of this would be:
def get_dxy(str1,str2):
    diffs = 0
    for x in str1:
        for y in str2:
            if x!=y:
                diffs+=1
    return diffs

def get_pi(str1):
    diffs = 0
    for i in range(len(str1)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(str1)):
            if str1[i]!=str1[j]:
                diffs+=1
    return diffs

I need to report these differences in separate columns. I am able to do this by using map_elements at each row:
df = df.with_columns( pl.col('pop_1')
                     .map_elements(get_pi, return_dtype=pl.Int64)
                     .alias('pi_1') 
                    )
df = df.with_columns( pl.col('pop_2')
                     .map_elements(get_pi, return_dtype=pl.Int64)
                     .alias('pi_2') 
                    )

df = df.with_columns(
        pl.struct("pop_1", "pop_2")
        .map_elements(lambda cols: get_dxy(cols["pop_1"], cols["pop_2"]), return_dtype=pl.Int64)
        .alias("dxy")
        )
df

| pop_1 | pop_2   | pi_1  |   pi_2  |  dxy  | 
|_______|_________|_______|_________|_______|
| "100" | "11002" |   2   |   8     |  9    |
| "0021"| "0000"  |   5   |   0     |  8    | 

However, my data is too large, and this method is not very fast. I was wondering what the fastest way to accomplish this using Polars built-in tools would be (perhaps without using map_elements?)
Could I get some hints in how to do this?

Please construct a [mre] so we can set up the a dataframe the same way you have. Also, how are you defining a "difference"? And what to you want the output to look like?

I'm still confused. How is "difference" defined? What is the difference between pi_1, pi_2, and dxy?

pi_1 is the column that results from applying the function "get_pi" to the rows of column pop_1 (pi_2 results from applying get_pi to pop_2), and dxy results from applying get_dxy two both columns pop_1 and pop_2. Sorry for this, seems like I didn't explained correctly my problem

It's still entirely unclear. Please update your question and explain in detail how you arrive at 2, 5, 8, 0, 9, and 8 for the desired results. It's unclear how the functions you shared would get to those values, and it's even more unclear what exactly they are supposed to compute. What "differences"? What does the "number" of differences between "100" and "0021" even mean and how does that change if there were more? You say you get these results by "applying the function" - please share the code if it actually works as you intend, and the only thing you want to know is to do it faster.

You are trying to optimize code that already works. Maybe try [codereview.se] with a complete example of your code and a more thorough explanation of what you're trying to accomplish.

Thank you guys for your comments. I have provided the code I am trying to optimize. Sorry for my misleading question!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you use some existing "string difference" algorithms? e.g. levenshtein? The polars_ds plugin has several from the [tag:rapidfuzz] library. https://github.com/rapidfuzz/rapidfuzz-rs

I didn't know about this plugin. Will read the docs. Thank you jqurious!

Do those algorithms work for you? Or do you need the specific values in your python functions?

These should be faster, specially for long strings.
def get_pi_2(string):
    diffs = 0
    string_length = len(string)
    chars = set(string)
    for char in chars:
        reps = string.count(char)
        diffs += (string_length - reps) * reps
    return diffs // 2  # differences are counted twice

def get_dxy_2(str1, str2):
    diffs = 0
    str2_length = len(str2)
    chars = set(str1)
    for char in chars:
        diffs += str2_length - str1.count(char)
    return diffs

list(set(...)) could be used instead of just sets to get a small boost in the for loop, but because there are few elements (only numbers and letters), the difference may not justify that additional conversion.

It is possible to implement similar logic using "native" Polars operations.
get_pi()
If you reshape with .unpivot() you could generate the combination of string slices with:

.int_ranges()
.str.len_chars()

(df.with_row_index()
   .unpivot(index="index")
   .with_columns(str_len = pl.col.value.str.len_chars())
   .with_columns(char_id = pl.int_ranges(1, pl.col.str_len))
   .explode("char_id")
)

shape: (12, 5)
┌───────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ index ┆ variable ┆ value ┆ str_len ┆ char_id │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ u32   ┆ str      ┆ str   ┆ u32     ┆ i64     │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 0     ┆ pop_1    ┆ 100   ┆ 3       ┆ 1       │
│ 0     ┆ pop_1    ┆ 100   ┆ 3       ┆ 2       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_1    ┆ 0021  ┆ 4       ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_1    ┆ 0021  ┆ 4       ┆ 2       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_1    ┆ 0021  ┆ 4       ┆ 3       │
│ …     ┆ …        ┆ …     ┆ …       ┆ …       │
│ 0     ┆ pop_2    ┆ 11002 ┆ 5       ┆ 3       │
│ 0     ┆ pop_2    ┆ 11002 ┆ 5       ┆ 4       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_2    ┆ 0000  ┆ 4       ┆ 1       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_2    ┆ 0000  ┆ 4       ┆ 2       │
│ 1     ┆ pop_2    ┆ 0000  ┆ 4       ┆ 3       │
└───────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┘

You can .str.slice() out the first char and the "rest of the string".
.str.count_matches() and some arithmetic can then be used to count the number of diffs.
(df.with_row_index()
   .unpivot(index="index")
   .with_columns(str_len = pl.col.value.str.len_chars())
   .with_columns(char_id = pl.int_ranges(1, pl.col.str_len))
   .explode("char_id")
   .with_columns(
      (pl.col.str_len - pl.col.char_id)
      - pl.col.value.str.slice(pl.col.char_id)
          .str.count_matches(pl.col.value.str.slice(pl.col.char_id - 1, 1))
   )
   .group_by("index", "variable")
   .agg(pl.col.str_len.sum())
   .with_columns(pl.col.variable.str.replace(r"^pop", "pi"))
   .pivot(on="variable", index="index")
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ index ┆ pi_1 ┆ pi_2 │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ u32   ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 5    ┆ 0    │
│ 0     ┆ 2    ┆ 8    │
└───────┴──────┴──────┘

get_dxy()
A similar approach can be used for the dxy count.
If you use .str.split("") to turn one of the strings into a list, then explode.
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(pl.col.pop_1.str.split(""))
   .explode("pop_1")
)

shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ index ┆ pop_1 ┆ pop_2 │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ u32   ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 11002 │
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 11002 │
│ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 11002 │
│ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 0000  │
│ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 0000  │
│ 1     ┆ 2     ┆ 0000  │
│ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 0000  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┘

The number of diffs is then just .len_chars() - .count_matches()
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(pl.col.pop_1.str.split(""))
   .explode("pop_1")
   .with_columns(dxy = 
      pl.col.pop_2.str.len_chars() 
      - pl.col.pop_2.str.count_matches(pl.col.pop_1)
   )
   .group_by("index")
   .agg(pl.col.dxy.sum())
)

shape: (2, 2)
┌───────┬─────┐
│ index ┆ dxy │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ u32   ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ 0     ┆ 9   │
│ 1     ┆ 8   │
└───────┴─────┘

You could combine into a single frame using joins.
(df.with_row_index()
   .join(df_pi.join(df_dxy, on="index"), on="index", how="left")
)

